Convergence of $p$-series for p=2 in the case of multi-indices.
We all know that the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty} 1/k^{2}$ converges. But is it true that $\sum_{|k|=1}^{\infty} 1/|k|^{2}$ converges when $k\in \mathbb{N}_{0}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{N}_{0}$ (n-times)?
I was trying to understand the proof of Theorem IX.1 from the book--
"METHODS OF MODERN MATHEMATICAL PHYSICS II: FOURIER ANALYSIS. SELF-ADJOINTNESS by MICHAEL REED and BARRY SIMON".
I understood everything completely but the uniform convergence of the series $$\sum\limits_{k\in K_{\epsilon}} \left((\epsilon/2)^{n/2} e^{ik\cdot x}, f\right) (\epsilon/2)^{n/2} e^{ik\cdot x},$$
where $f$ belongs to the set of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $$K_{\epsilon} = \left\{ (\pi\epsilon) k \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}^{n} \right\}.$$
To solve the problem, I got the question I posted here.
However, it would be beneficial if anyone could solve the uniform convergence of the above series.

The uniform convergence you are asking about is not that simple. The series $\sum_{k_{1}}\sum_{k_{2}}\frac{1}{k_{1}^2+k_{2}^2}$ is divergent. Think of the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx dy}{x^2+y^2}$ which diverges.

@Medo It does not make sense even with $\Bbb N_0$. Now it's correct.

@medo Thanks for your comments. So, to prove the uniform convergence, the problem needs to be approached in another way

@Rintu29 Thank you for the interesting question. The convergence definitely has to do with the decay of the Fourier coefficients of $f$.
